# Multiply Varchar(50) column and int column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
select convert(int, Price_Each) * Quantity_Ordered as Total_Sale 
from data
```

I am trying to multiply two columns where data type of `Price_Each` is `varchar(50)`, and data type of `Quantity_Ordered` is `int`.

Even after convert and casting I am having the same error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' $11.95' to data type int.

My table name is "DATA"

| Order ID | Product | Quantity Ordered | Price Each |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 176558 | USB-C Charging Cable | 2 | $11.95 |
| 176559 | Bose SoundSport Headphones | 1 | $99.99 |

My problem statement is: create new columns named as total sales per person (by multiplying quantity order with the price each)

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: "data type of Price_Each is varchar(50) " - this is your problem. Use a numeric type for prices

Comment: you cannot convert dollar sign to int, remove it

Comment: And you **cannot** convert a value like `11.95` to `int` since it's **not** an `INT` - it should be a `DECIMAL(20,2)` (or something similar)

Comment: `convert(money, price_each)` should work, but you should adjust the type of the column rather than convert it every time.

Comment: "where data type of Price_Each is varchar(50)"   - fix the actual problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment by @Jeroen Mostert, you need to convert to `money` which handles the currency symbol `$`. The query would be :

```
select convert(money, Price_Each) * Quantity_Ordered as Total_Sale 
from data
```

And you should actually change your column datatype to money, then you can easily multiply without casting and definitely you will get more benefits while doing any other processing with this column.

```
alter table [DATA]
alter column Price_Each money
```